# Get the size of list of documents in mongo db

Tags: mongodb

I want to get the size of the list of documents in mongodb.

```
db.getCollection('eventDetails').find({"dateTime" : { $gte : new ISODate("2018-05-01T12:00:00Z") },"dateTime" : { $lte : new ISODate("2018-05-31T23:59:59Z") }})
```

I want to get the size of the documents returned by the above mentioned query.

I tried the following query

```
var cursor = db.getCollection('eventDetails').find({"dateTime" : { $gte : new ISODate("2018-05-01T12:00:00Z") },"dateTime" : { $lte : new ISODate("2018-05-31T23:59:59Z") }})
var size = 0;
cursor.forEach(
    function(doc){
        size += Object.bsonsize(doc)
    }
);
print(size)
```

Each time execute the query, i get different results.
Let me know how to get the size of the documents in mongodb

Comment: Yes the database is not getting updated

Comment: Can you please update your code to reflect the documents returned each time you have executed the code along with output of size. I have tried the same on my collections and found the value of size unaffected.

Answer (score 3):

As per MongoDB jira blog documentation [Real document size in collection](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-12984) and also MongoDB documentation [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/mongo-shell/) the **`Object.bsonsize(<document>)`** prints the BSON size of a `<document>` in bytes.

To find the size of all documents in a collection:

```
Object.bsonsize(db.collection.find( {dbname:"collectionname"}))
```

For Example

```
> use test
switched to db test
> db.createCollection("StackExchange");
{ "ok" : 1 }

> show collections
StackExchange
>

> db.StackExchange.insertOne({"Name" : "user3138864", "Password" : "abc123"})
{
        "acknowledged" : true,
        "insertedId" : ObjectId("5b740353194beb82d3752206")
}
> db.StackExchange.findOne()
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5b740353194beb82d3752206"),
        "Name" : "user3138864",
        "Password" : "abc123"
}
> db.StackExchange.find().pretty()
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5b740353194beb82d3752206"),
        "Name" : "user3138864",
        "Password" : "abc123"
}
> Object.bsonsize(db.StackExchange.find( {m040:"StackExchange"}))
45734
```

For further your ref [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/mongo-shell/) and [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/74312/understanding-document-size-in-mongodb)

Comment: the mongodb.com/docs links in this post are stale… does anybody have an up-to-date link?